# Is linear kernel SVM performance between features indicative of RBF kernel SVM performance?

Tags: svm, feature-selection

I have feature set 1 and feature set 2. If a linear kernel SVM performs better ("better" meaning greater classification accuracy) when using feature set 1, does this guarantee that a properly tuned rbf kernel SVM will also perform better using feature set 1?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, there is no way to know a priori that a rbf kernel will perform better on feature set 1. And without actually tuning your C parameter in the linear kernel I would not conclude that feature set 1 is actually better.